# Sonata Admin blank dashboard

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-2.4

I have a few of their projects on Symfony 2. On one of them today itch to do a total upgrade to the newest versions. Prior to that, everything worked perfectly. And the projects themselves, and sonata admin and authorization.

After the upgrade, I did not knurl old configs, and carefully read the manuals for all the vendors, and prescribed all over again. There were a few problems, but the project has started pretty quickly. The site works, authorization works, not only works admin panel. Today, a day fumbling, and can not understand why I have the admin screen blank.

[image]

in /src/Itfrogs/SiteBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
...
    sonata.admin.dictionary.group:
            class: Itfrogs\SiteBundle\Admin\Model\DictionaryGroupsAdmin
            tags:
                - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Content, label: Dictionary Group }
            arguments:
                - ~
                - Itfrogs\SiteBundle\Entity\DictionaryGroup
                - ~
            calls:
                - [ setTranslationDomain, [ItfrogsSiteBundle]]
...
```

in main config.yml

```
...
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        #sonata.admin_doctrine_orm.block.audit:
        #    contexts:   [admin]

        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.action:
        sonata.block.service.rss:
        sonata.media.block.media:

sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            -
                position: left
                type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list
...
```

I think it's basic. Rest on a manual. The class  Itfrogs\SiteBundle\Admin\Model\DictionaryGroupsAdmin and the entity Itfrogs\SiteBundle\Entity\DictionaryGroup remained the same.

Before loading the class does not reach. I checked.

Prompt, where to search?
If any more configs need tell me - I'll post.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you're using the latest Sonata Admin Bundle it should be something like this according to [the documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/installation.html):

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sonata user bundle with FOSUser bundle then you may not have the right permissions to view your pages.
If you're in fact using FOSUser, Try in command line:
php app/console fos:user:create adminuser --super-admin

You can find more [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/command_line_tools.md)

**hint: but you must configure the sonata block in your configuration

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
```